# not work validation after change ngmodel in ui-select programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am changing `ui-select` `ngmodel` value in controller programmatically.
`ui-select` show value but validation is invalid.
validation is correctly when select value with mouse click but programmatically not work .
how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have code to show?

Comment: Please provide your html code of ui-select and controller code where you set value so that we can help you.